# how to override a method defined at __init__.py?

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to use a module (pandas_access) witch has an issue on a method (_extract_dtype) defined at `__init__.py`

What is the proper way (or any) to overwrite a method defined on `__init__.py`?

Comment: Take a look at [monkey patch](https://web.archive.org/web/20120730014107/http://wiki.zope.org/zope2/MonkeyPatch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just "monkey patch" the method e.g.

```
def _extract_dtype_patched(self):
    print("Patched version")

TargetClass._extract_dtype = _extract_dtype_patched
```

Although care must be taken, per @bracco23's link above, and if you've discovered a bug it would be cool to report it to the upstream project!